# How to use pip to install packages using MinGW-w64 compiler on Windows 7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, distutils

I'm using Python 3.4.1 64 bit on Windows 7. When I tried to install scikit-image using pip, I ran into the popular problem: "unable to find vcvarsall.bat".  I made sure that I have both Visual Studio 2009 and 2010 redistributable installed and also added VS90COMNTOOLS and VS100COMNTOOLS to environment variable. But that didn't help. The same error persisted.

Then I decided to give MinGW-w64 a try. So I installed it. Add the bin folder to PATH. Then create a distutils.cfg file that has this code

```
[Build]
compiler = mingw-w64
```

Then I get this error message: "don't know how to compile C/C++ code on platform 'nt' with 'mingw-w64' compiler". How should I solve this?

P.S I know I can download binaries from Christoph Gohlke's page, but I'd still like to know how to do this on my own.

Comment: I will not help you with mingw, but have to tips: once you manage to compile the package, create "wheel" format of it (e.g. using $ pip wheel <package>) and install from it. This will work for the same platform even if mingw environment is not present.

Another tip: if there is already exe or egg for your platform, you shall be able using `wheel`
command to convert it to wheel package and install from it.

Good luck with compiling packages on Windows - it is not easy.

Comment: Error message happens because Python doesn't know about mingw-w64: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/distutils/ccompiler.py#l960

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install unofficial whl for Windows listed here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Got you link and search for "scikit-image"

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer to your question, but you might want to take a look at [Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/). It it allows you to install packages without compiling them and already comes with several useful packages such as NumPy, Pandas, SciPy, Matplotlib, and Jupyter.

You can install scikit-image with one command:

```
conda install scikit-image
```

Or to update it:

```
conda update scikit-image
```

I always recommend Anaconda to anyone who is starting to use Python on Windows - saves you a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing `scikit-image` from the cmd prompt from Windows:
[Scikit-image installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFoBO.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

All I did to install using pip was go into the command prompt and type the following. For my example, I'm installing numpy, but you can use it to install whatever you need.

```
>pip install numpy
```

Simple as that. Hope it helps!

Comment: That's only useful for modules that don't require compiling (e.g., modules that provide a binary wheel).